# Can't create mysql table in workbench

Tags: mysql

I have created a mysql database testing. A table 'table1' was created inside it.
But when i tried to read that table in using java it, gives an error like 
'**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testing.table1' doesn't exist**'
I created table1 and inserted some data using insert tab and also clicked '**applychanges to data**' button.But It doesn't work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wIB.jpg)
There is no file table1.frm which is related to that table in the path '**C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\testing**'.But default database 'sakila' and its tables are working perfectly.How to save my table??

Comment: Have you tried with a table name without number ?

Comment: you have created the model. goto menu [Databases] -> synchronize Model and complete it that will create your table in your localhost

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have created tables in design view and saved those will not pushed to the DB. In order to apply them on DB you have to go to the menu "Database -> Forward Engineering" and generate the scripts and apply